As an unmarried girl do I have to follow Sutak after maternal grandfather death? Can I wash hair, what can I not eat? and what else needs to be follow
As an unmarried girl do I have to follow Sutak after maternal grandfather death? Can I wash hair, what can I not eat? and what else needs to be followed? Answer based on Hinduism facts because I live away from family and dont know what to do

I don't think so. Best to confirm with one's family priest.
